# Is there any way that I can set background colour when exporting Json to xlsx

Tags: excel, angular

I am trying to export an json object to xlsx using XLSX.write() in Angular,I can set column value using below snippet but styles are not working

```
Worksheet[‘A1’] =
 {
  v:”qwerty”,
  s:{fill: {bgColor:{rgb:”ff6600”}}
 };
```

Comment: you seem to have a missing }

Comment: Though I added } still it’s not working.     Worksheet[‘A1’] =
 {
  v:”qwerty”,
  s:{fill: {bgColor:{rgb:”ff6600”}}}
 };

Comment: reproduce your issue on stackblitz help us help you